# How to use guard to unrwap optionals in a dictionary?

Tags: swift, option-type

I am parsing a dictionary with stuff to generate a Rocket object. In the parsing method i use guard to do my checks. Is it possible to use guard to both check for existing value in a dictionary, and unwrap it at the same time?

```
let rocketDictionary : [String : String?] = [ "name" : nil, "numberOfThrusters" : nil ]

func generateRocketSchematics(rocketDictionary : [String : String?]) {

    guard let rocketName = rocketDictionary["name"] as? String else {
         print("no rocket name")
         return
    }

    print(rocketName)

}
```

This code won't compile because of the `as? String`. If i remove that, the rocketName will be a String? Is it possible to write the guard statement so that it will return a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern matching with `guard/case`:

```
func generateRocketSchematics(rocketDictionary : [String : String?]) {

    guard case let rocketName?? = rocketDictionary["name"] else {
        print("no rocket name")
        return
    }

    print(rocketName) // rocketName is a String
}
```

`rocketName??` is a synonym for `.Some(.Some(rocketName))`, so

```
 case let rocketName?? = rocketDictionary["name"]
```

matches the case where `rocketDictionary["name"]` (which has the
type `String??`) is not `nil`, and the unwrapped value (which has
the type `String?`) is also not `nil`. The doubly-unwrapped value
(of type `String`) is then assigned to `rockedName`.